A short story about a SF author telling his friends, as a joke, a harebrained SF story, and what follows
I read this humorous short story in a SF&F collection, more than 20 years ago. I am positive is it by a very famous SF writer but I forgot whom.
It is a fiction, but in a world that, alas, could very well be ours. So technically, neither SF nor Fantasy, but because of its author and the decision of the editor to publish it (and this was a collection so probably it had already been previously published in an SF&F magazine) I consider it is "on topic".
It is about a SF writer telling to his friends, just for fun, having first claimed he was a expert on the field and present at the event, a totally harebrained story about a nuclear reactor gone critical that instead of exploding, has created an antigravity field around it (the "anti-gravity" tag does not exist, so I used the "artificial-gravity" tag instead).
Unfortunately for him, some crackpot heard him, and believed that his story was true rather than a joke. So his story was published in one of the many pseudoscience publications, mentioning his name and calling him a reliable authority, an "expert" who had personally attended the event.
So he kept receiving an avalanche of letters, some calling him a liar and pointing out the many scientific inconsistencies, but most of them be "believers" who wanted more details.

It is, as you say, a purely mundane story about a man who is overheard making an outlandish claim and then is believed by others.

@valorum Yes, but quite a few editors decided to include it in their collections... I am not the only one to believe that though it is indeed "mundane" in fits into SF&F spirit.

@Valorum - I think if the interior speculative fiction story is substantial enough—i.e. its own narrative, not just a few sentences summarizing a claim—we can count it for that reason, in much the same vein as the film version of The Wizard of Oz. Otherwise, I agree, merely having science in a story does not make it "science fiction," otherwise we would be taking questions about the TV show The Big Bang Theory.

@Adamant - I'm not voting to close because it certainly has the smell of sci-fi about it, even if it's not strictly on-topic

@Alfred - There are endless examples of non-sci-fi-stories being published in Sci-fi magazines.

@Adamant The "interior speculative fiction" indeed represents more than half the whole story, is quite substantial, and uses very incorrect but rather original "speculative physics". It is indeed close to "Wizard of Oz", not BBT.

@Alfred you've got enough reputation on this site to just create a new tag, if its needed.  I've done that with an edit (now in the review queue cos I don't have as much rep)

Apparently not the one you're looking for, your description has some elements in common with Charles Stross's A Tall Tale.

@Ray Some elements in common, yes. But the "inside story" in my story was clearly a joke from the beginning, not attempting to look as serious science. In yours, there is some ambiguity...

@Alfred Yeah, there's no way it's the one you're looking for. But if someone in the future is searching for that one, it's possible they would find this question while doing so, so I wanted to put the answer here for their hypothetical benefit (but decided against making it an actual answer, since it's the wrong answer).

"What Goes Up" by Arthur C. Clarke, one of his Tales from the White Hart.

The story narrated by Purvis is provoked by the entry of a U.F.O. enthusiast into the White Hart. In order to quell his stories, Purvis spins a tale describing an attempt by an Australian researcher nicknamed "Dr. Cavor" to develop atomic power. Cavor designs and builds an atomic generator, but by some accident, he ends up creating a field of lower gravity around the generator, such that from a physics point of view it has been elevated to an altitude of several thousand miles



The story is enough to silence the U.F.O. believer; however, Purvis later gets thousands of letters from other believers, much to his annoyance, because the story was not meant to be taken seriously.

Here's the listing of where the story has appeared.
PS. I appreciate your use of the word hare-brained - there is a rabbit in the story.

Yes ! Now you mention it, I remember about the rabbit (or rabbits ?) ! My use of "harebrained" was purely coincidental... or maybe a subliminal memory ?

"Dr. Cavor" is definitely a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Men_in_the_Moon
